# Using JSON API's with OAUTH2 authentication

Tags: json, oauth-2.0

I've been asked to secure some API's using OAUTH2 (e.g., no person in the loop). I've found I can leverage the [mod_oauth2](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_oauth2) work in Apache, but my original API's POSTed JSON and the OAUTH2 spec requires x-www-form-urlencoded (and rejects requests with application/json content). What is the appropriate thing to do? Change the API to use form encoded content and marshal the JSON using stringify and encodeURIComponent? I was hoping the OAUTH2 authorization could occur and the original payload (e.g., JSON) would then be forwarded to the API Service. However, there isn't a standard to allow finding the token in JSON so it seems I need to supply x-www-form-urlencoded content with the token and my application content in the POST body.

I'd seen a draft for using JSON-based requests with OAUTH2 here: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-richer-oauth-json-request-00.html

But it seems to have expired.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a client gets a token from an Authorization Server (AS) using form URL encoded messages - eg via a client_id and client_secret, then calls the API using JSON. The API's only job is then to validate tokens received in JSON requests - see [Curity Guides](https://curity.io/resources/guides/api/) for some examples.

So I would aim to use an AS that provides tokens to secure your APIs. Eg a cloud provider or a free / open source one. If for some reason you can't do that in the short term, then follow the same pattern: eg add a token service that deals with form URL encoded messages and token issuing - keep this responsibility out of your business APIs.

As always in this type of solution it it is worth thinking carefully about how you expect current and future clients to authenticate and get tokens. This is usually the most important question and an AS will provide many options here.

Comment: Thanks Gary -- please see my solution above. I'd created my own AS as an exercise to learn more about OAuth, but my initial tests sent the access token in the POST body, thus requiring x-form-urlencoded Content-Type, but the Apache mod_oauth2 provides flexibility to find the access token elsewhere (e.g., in a specified Header) freeing me to send whatever payload is desired.

Comment: Yep - that's standard and recommended - client sends the token in the Authorization header, then uses its preferred format for the business data.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I believe I can specify a header location for the access token and leave the POST body as application/json so once the request is authorized (by grabbing the access token from the header and sending to the AS for validation), my POST payload can be forwarded to the downstream API service as is (e.g., in JSON). E.g., I shouldn't need to have the access token in the POST body, thus freeing me to use whatever type of Content-Type my APIs require.